# Regarding pointers of c programing

Tags: c, pointers

Please, if anyone know what's wrong in this tell me

```
#include"stdio.h"

void main() {
    int a = 10;
    int* p = &a;
    void** q = &p;
    printf("memory address=%d\n",(int*)*q);
}
```

Here is the compiler error:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer
>   type[-Wincompatible- pointer-types]
>        void **q=&p;
>
> ptr3.c:7:25: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but 
>   argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]  printf("memory
>   address=%d\n",(int*)*q);
>                           ~^    ~~~~~~~~
>                           %ls

Is compiler wants to say that I cannot point a `int` type pointer using `void` pointer?

Comment: `void **` is not a "void pointer". It is a pointer to void pointer. And it is incompatible with a pointer to `int` pointer.

Comment: Apart from the aliasing error, use `*(int**)q` + use `%p`.

Comment: Use `%p` to print a pointer.

Comment: Use `(void*)` when passing a pointer to `%p` specifier in `printf`.

Comment: sir i think you are all correct but can you please tell me a solution to a problem regarding this

Comment: There is no problem stated to provide a solution for.

Comment: *"if anyone know what's wrong in this tell me"* - it looks like the compiler is doing a fine job of that very thing,isn't it?

Comment: int a=10;void *b,**c;    b=&a,c=&b;                                                                             now how to print the value of a by using pointer c , while typecasting only at printing time

Comment: `int a = 10; void *b = &a; void **c = &b;`. You can: `void *d = *c; int *e = d; int f = *e; printf("%d"\n f);` or just `printf ("%d", *(int*)*c);`

Comment: Thanks to you all for your responses..

Comment: It's not clear what the desired result is. Are you trying to convert `q` back to an `int *`, then dereference it to get 10?

Comment: `#include "stdio.h"` should be `#include <stdio.h>`. `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: `void **` is not compatible with `int **`.  Either declare `q` as `int **`, or `p` as `void *`.  And, what *exactly* are you trying to print out?  The value in `a`, or the address of `a` (value of `p`), or the address of `p` (the value of `q`), or the address of `q`?

Comment: help in this,int a=10; void *b,**c,***d;   b=&a,c=&b,d=&c;

Comment: now how to print value of a using d while typecasting only in printf.                        pls hlp.

Comment: `printf("%d", *(int*)**d);` You just increase number of `*` : )

Comment: Look it that way. If you have a `int ****a;`, then you need the same amount of `*` to get an int, so `int b = ****a`.

Comment: Thanks kamil cuk sir . Now i truly understand this concept.* is just working as links, connected * shows connected links. thank u.

Answer (score 1):

> Is compiler wants to say that I cannot point a int type pointer using
>   void pointer?

`void ** q` is type `void **` while `int * p` is type `int *`. Hence this line: `void ** q = &p;` warrants a compiler warning as the types are not compatible.

If you typecast `&p` to a `void *` then the warning in your question will go away: `void ** q = (void *)&p;`

This line: `printf("memory address=%d\n",(int*)*q);` should also cause a compiler warning because `(int *)*q` is type `int *` but the `%d` format specifier is expecting an `int`. If you use the format specifier `%p` then this warning will go away as well.